# How to get the name of a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, filenames, shutil

Ok so I have a python script that will move its self to the desktop when its run, but I want it to be able to move itself no matter what its name is. My current code only moves it when it is called a specific thing.

My current code is

```
shutil.move("moveMe.py", "C:/Users/" + user + "/desktop/")
```

I've experimented with __ name__ because from what its name implies it would be the name of the file but I'm not 100% sure how to use it yet as I'm quite new to python

Comment: Try using the built-in variable `__file__`, which always resolves to the current location of the file being executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `__file__` or import sys and use `sys.argv[0]`